# Core plot: Make x-axis ticks evenly spaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have a core plot graph in which I have prices data. The x-axis represents the time, while the y represents the price. I've determined that it's this code specifically that determines the space in between the tick marks:

```
CGFloat dateCount = [timestamps count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
float i = 0;
for (NSString *date in timestampStrings) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    CGFloat location = i+=spaceBetweenXAxisTicks; // Here's where the space between is set
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
```

Is there some way to dynamically set the space in between so the last tick hits the right of the graph? Thanks!

Comment: You just have to make you axis range a multiple of your tic mark spacing for the end to end in a tic. Also put the `+=` part as it's own line on the previous line, I've never seen that written like this before, bug?

Comment: @boyfarrell the `+=` seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spaceBetweenXAxisTicks` should be the length of the plot space `xRange` divided by the number of tick marks minus one (1).

Comment: You have no idea how unbelievably happy I am at this moment. I have been trying to solve this problem fruitlessly for the past 48 hours after learning what core-plot is. You are a beautiful man and you have created a beautiful graphing system. I applaud you.